# Binding List to a ListBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemssource

I have a class called `Person`, with just name, age and gender properties. And I also have a `List<Person>` of 5 people (hard-coded for now, but not relevant). I want to bind it to a ListBox through XAML so it has three TextBlocks for each of the properties:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=gender}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=age}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is that I don't know what to use as a data context or item source or whatever.
Any ideas?

Comment: The itemssource of the ListBox should be your hardcoded List.

Answer (score 11):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=gender}" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=age}" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and in your code behind (ViewModel):

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get { return people; } }
```

You can omit `Path=` in your bindings because it is the default property

Comment: Just for the completness, `People` must be a propertie. So you have to write `public ObservableCollection<Person> People {get;set;}`.